# django - python: failed using reverse : no reverse match

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following Views:

```
def default_new (request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post = EquipmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('calbase:default_detail', args=(id,)))
    else:
        form = EquipmentForm()
    return render(request, 'calbase/default_edit.html', {'form':form})

class default_detail (generic.DetailView):
    model = Equipment
    template_name = 'calbase/default_detail.html'
```

And urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.default, name = 'default'),
    url(r'^default/((?P<id>\d+)/$)', views.default_detail.as_view(), name = 'default_detail'),
    url(r'^default/new/$', views.default_new, name = 'default_new'),
]
```

What I would like to do here is just to take in a form input, save it, and then redirect to its detail view. However, although the form is correctly saved, it always give me errors like:

```
NoReverseMatch at /calbase/default/new/
Reverse for 'default_detail' with arguments '(<built-in function id>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['calbase/default/((?P<id>\\d+)/$)']
```

Could somebody help me figuring out what's wrong here pls?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are using [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#id), which is a built in function.

When you call `form.save()`, it will return the `Post` instance. Use `post.id` (or `post.pk` if you prefer) to get the id of the post.

```
def default_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EquipmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('calbase:default_detail', args=(post.id,)))
```

You also have too many parentheses in your url pattern. It should be:

```
url(r'^default/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.default_detail.as_view(), name = 'default_detail'),
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried that, it gives me "'EquipmentForm' object has no attribute 'id'"

Comment: I didn't spot that `post` was a form, not a `Post`. That's very confusing! Use `form` for your form, and `post` for your `Post` instance, it will make your code easier to understand! I've updated the answer now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. And thanks so much for helping. I tried your updates and it is now "Reverse for 'default_detail' with arguments '(28,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['calbase/default/((?P<id>\\d+)/$)']". I am wondering if the problem is with the urls?

Comment: Maybe you have not set up the `calbase` namespace. Try `reverse('default_detail', args=(post.id,))`

Comment: I am pretty sure that I set up the namespace fine and yeah i also tried doing that and still. This is driving me crazy...

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with you url pattern as well.